# laravel excel import incorrect data value (varchar)

Tags: excel, laravel, import

I been trying to import value from Po No excel field to pono MySQL field with this code below. in some cases the value that been imported to MySQL are incorrect.

**value on excel** : 4500001396 **meanwhile imported** : 205034100
**value on excel** : 4110002876 **meanwhile imported** : -184964420

I tried to `dd` the $row['po_no'] and the value that appears on the page is **correct**. but what added to the DB is **wrong**. what should I do?

**note** : some of the value I dont import because the excel field keep changing right on the development process and i leave it null on DB.

here is the model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Invoice extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "invoices";

    protected $fillable = [
        //Meta Data
        'id',
        'po_no',
        'inv_month',
        'inv_year',
        'inv_no',
        'inv_sow',
        'vendor_name',
        'project_name',
        'inv_date',
        'submit_date',
        'est_paydate',
        'inv_net_value',
        'inv_ppn',
        'fp_no',
        'fp_status',
        'inv_est_payment',
        'inv_released_payment',
        'inv_remaining_payment',
        'payment_date',
        'inv_remark',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'po_no' => 'string',
    ];

}
```

here is the import.php code

```
class InvoiceImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        // dd($row['po_no']);
        if ($row['no_invoice'] == null) {
            return null;
        }

        $oldInvData = Invoice::where('inv_no', $row['no_invoice']);
        if ($oldInvData) {
            $oldInvData->delete();
        }

        $vendorName = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z ]/', '', $row['vendor']);
        $vendorName = strtoupper($vendorName);

        $projectName = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z ]/', '', $row['project']);
        $projectName = strtoupper($projectName);

        $invoiceRemark = ($row['remark_invoice'] == 'UNPAID') ? \App\Enum\PaidAndUnpaidEnum::UNPAID : \App\Enum\PaidAndUnpaidEnum::PAID;

        if($row['net_value'] != null) {
            $invNetValue = preg_replace('/[^0-9-]/', '', $row['net_value']);
        } else {
            $invNetValue = null;
        }
        
        $poNo = $row['po_no'];
        // dd($poNo);

        return new Invoice([
            'po_no' => $poNo,
            'inv_no' => $row['no_invoice'],
            'inv_month' => $row['bulan'],
            'inv_year' => $row['tahun'],
            'inv_sow' => $row['sow'],
            'vendor_name' => $vendorName,
            'project_name' => $projectName,
            'inv_net_value' => $invNetValue,
            'inv_remark' => $invoiceRemark,
            'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTime(),
            'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTime(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: which library you used to import excel file in controller?

Comment: I use maatwebsite/excel library @BilalSaad